# How to start WinRT application by running a batch file

Tags: windows-8, startup, windows-8.1

I have a WinRT application installed on my Windows 8.1 system. 
I want to run the WinRT application automatically when I boot my system.

I Kept the shortcut  icon of the WinRT application in Startup folder, but it says below error.

> C:\Program
>   File\WindowsApps\da514905-a804-40c0-862a-0658033dcbb5_1.0.0.21_x64..\App1.exe
>
> This Application can only run in the context of an app container.

If anybody knows how can I achieve this, then please let me know.

Thank you,
Shiva

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942006/auto-startup-a-metro-app?rq=1

Comment: Check out http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/10/28/how-to-setup-assigned-access-in-windows-8-1-kiosk-mode.aspx