# windows10 mobile auto startup

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, startup, windows-10-mobile

I'm looking for a method to start up an app. automatically at the boot time on the Windows10 mobile. 
I've found a same issue on the Windows8 metro app.

[Auto Startup a Metro App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942006/auto-startup-a-metro-app)

I know that the situation is not improved as long as I use the Pre-Launch function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-app-prelaunch

Would you please let me if you have another idea or information.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? for debugging purposes? or production ? is it a side load app?

Comment: Thank you to get in touch with me. I plan to produce a side load app. that will make some specific works at the boot time interacting with the user.